# ¿Cómo agregar un encabezado de puente para el juego de Metal en Xcode?

Tags: swift

Creé un juego de Metal en Xcode. Estoy planeando escribir la mayor parte en C y escribir la interfaz de usuario en Metal / Swift. Sin embargo, a diferencia de SwiftUI, para un juego de Metal si creo un archivo C, no me pide automáticamente que agregue un encabezado de puente. Así que investigo muchísimo e intento agregar uno, pero no lo reconoce. Aquí hay una captura de pantalla:
[image]

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Muchos esfuerzos de investigación me llevaron a "Agregar el nombre del encabezado de puente a esta configuración". Lo hago y no pasa nada. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal, por qué mienten los otros sitios web de investigación y cuál es la forma real de realizar esta tarea?

¡El error que obtengo es al tratar de llamar a una función C de forma rápida, porque NO RECONOCE EL ENCABEZADO DE PUENTE!

En `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  AsadefaCraft
//
//  Created by Asadefa on 3/8/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Asadefa. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        HandleApplicationStart((NSHomeDirectory() as NSString).utf8String) //Use of unresolved identifier 'HandleApplicationStart'
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    }
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

En `AsadefaCraft-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
#include "Initialize.h"
```

En `Initialize.h`:

```
extern void HandleApplicationStart(const char *const);
```

En `Initialize.c`:

```
void HandleApplicationStart(const char *const HomeDir) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar algo del código del archivo Bridging-Header y el error que te marca en el Xcode.

Comment: @Bicho lo hice.

Comment: Puedes agregar el error que te marca en el Xcode? o en qué línea del código para entender mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: @Bicho Ya lo hice. Leer de nuevo Es el comentario en la línea de código en AppDelegate